# Exporting massive gps tracks to a map

Tags: google-maps, gps, tracking, flow, movement-data

I have about 1000 vehicle equiped by a GPS sensor and 3G connection. 
Each vehicle feeds a csv file  -using 3G connection- with its current location every 5 sec. 
Each vehicle have its own CSV file.

At the end of the day, I end up with about 1000 CSV file, each one contain the vehicle track of the day.

My aim to export all the csv files to a map in a way to see the most frequented routes by time. For example at 5PM I want to have map showing the different roads colored from red to green to show the trafic flow rate at this time.

Of course the coordinates are not always so precise, so I will take into considerationerror margin. I will assume that any point outlying by 10m of a road is on that road.

Also, I have the possibility to create a database with all the 1000 vehicles data on it.

Now I think you have the big picture of the situation, if anyone could help and suggest a tool to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simmilar application a few time ago.
I registered my cellphone position, sending a CSV each 5 minutes, and inserting it in a postGIS database.

To sum up:

- Load csv in PostGIS database. I made it with shell script in the server, run each 5 minutes, and update the table.
- Filter the results on the database.
- Once in postgis, you can export it to a kml/geojson, in order to show it in google maps or simmilar. Filter by the id if the car, or whatever you need